# Best way to remove anything between <rt> and </rt> in HTML or TXT

Tags: html, string, text

I have 2GB files worth of HTML files across 2000 files
I am finding the best way to apply the following to everything:

1) DELETE anything thats between `<rt>` and `</rt>`

2) DELETE `<rt>, </rt>, <ruby>, </ruby>`

Here is an example input and output

Input:

```
<ruby>
    <span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-78">唐</span>
    <rt>
        <span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-79">とう</span>
    </rt>
    <span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-80">突</span>
    <rt>
        <span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-81">とつ</span>
    </rt>
</ruby>
<span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-82"></span>
```

Output:

```
<span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-78">唐</span>
<span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-80">突</span>
<span class="kobospan" id="calibre_link-82"></span>
```

The most desirable solution I am looking for is a .bat file which I can just drag stuffs in and make it apply the changes.

The least desirable solution is a program with a command code, which I can automatically apply all the changes with a click.

At the very least, I want to be able to manually do this one by one.

Comment: Is there any limitation or preference ? Such as using python on Windows 10, or PHP - CLI mode on any OS, etc.

Comment: Im using Windows 7 or Windows 10. I am okay with any program on windows that i can learn quickly, altho i have a preference towards excel/word/txt editor solutions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it a 1MB per text file?? any format?? Refer to sample you provided, is it 1 data per line ?? What is your means of one by one ? One file ? One convert ??? Whats is your meaning of the txt editor solution ?? is it a marco script ran at text editor ? Such as Emeditor ? https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/extensibility/scriptable-macros/

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been two weeks and you haven't gotten any answers, I can provide you with this solution even though it is not the ideal way to do it:

Open a file in Notepad++ and do a regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what: `</?ruby>\s+?^|<rt>.*?</rt>\s+?^`

Put nothing in the "Replace with" box and click "Replace All".

Make sure you have selected "Regular expression" search mode and have checked the box for ". matches newline"